# Trouble with importing CSV into SQL Server using BULK IMPORT when the CSV has formatting errors

Tags: sql-server, csv-import, bulk-import

I am trying to import a `.CSV` file into my SQL Server database. This is the script I am using:

```
BULK INSERT <table_name>
FROM '/data.txt'
WITH
(
  FIRSTROW = 2,
  FORMAT='CSV',
  ERRORFILE = '/RowErrors.txt',
  MAXERRORS = 100
)
```

The trouble is my CSV has rows like the following in it.

```
"1-XY-YYYY","","","",""GXXXXX","SuXXXXXXXX","1-XY-YYYY"
```

Note the `""GXXXXX"` in column 5.

The import stops with the following error when it gets to that row

> Bulk load failed due to invalid column value in CSV data file

Is there some way to get the importer to ignore data formatting error like we can with the `MAXERRORS` property?

Comment: In my encounters with bcp and bulk insert the fomat of quoted fields needs to be consistent. I suspect you are going to have to pre-process your file eg a regex search and replace for any `""` that are not followed by a comma.

Comment: I was hoping not to have to do that. The double double quote is not the only formatting issue. There are several other errors and it would be impossible to find all of them. Mutch easier just to ignore them.

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out. Rather than trying to hack around broken .csv files the originator of the file should be made to write .csv files correctly. There's an RFC and everything: [RFC 4180 Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning ah man, I wish I could get the originator to fix the file. But, unfortunately, I am stuck with it.

Comment: *.csv files always have host of problems where column delimiters, column separators, invisible characters like null terminators \0, special characters based on encoding, and line breaks are in the middle of the actual data.
The most reliable format for data feeds is XML.